# How to separate my event handling from HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

My code is working fine but is there a way to do this without having my event (onclick) in the HTML form. How can I use an eventlistener on this?

Here is the HTML:

```
<strong>Select Your fees Options</strong></label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="fee" id="exc" value="12000.00" onclick = "updateFee()"  required><label>PTA and Excursion and Magazine Fee N12,000.00</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="fee"  id="fol" value="3000.00" onclick = "updateFee()" ><label>Folder Fee <b>(optional)</b> N3,000.00</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="fee"  id="ext"    value="15000.00"  onclick = "updateFee()" ><label>Extra Lesson <b>(optional)</b> N15,000.00</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="fee"  id="clu" value="15000.00"  onclick = "updateFee()"><label>Club <b>(optional)</b> N15,000.00</label><br>
<!--total fee is here-->   
<p><b>Total Fee:
<input  name="amt" id="amt" class="form-control number" type="text" /> <br>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
<script> 
function updateFee(){
var  totFee = 0;
var fee=document.getElementsByName("fee");
for (i = 0; i < fee.length; i++)
{
if (fee[i].checked == true)
{
totFee += parseInt(fee[i].value, 10);       
}
}
amount = totFee  ;
document.getElementById("amt").value = amount;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please indent your code properly. By the way, you don't need to compare boolean values to `true`; just write `if (fee[i].checked)`.

Comment: Indenting done! Thank you for the correction. @torazaburo

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript/[jQuery](http://jquery.com)

In your case it would be

```
<strong>Select Your fees Options</strong></label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="fee" id="exc" value="12000.00" required><label>PTA and Excursion and Magazine Fee N12,000.00</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="fee"  id="fol" value="3000.00"><label>Folder Fee <b>(optional)</b> N3,000.00</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="fee"  id="ext"    value="15000.00"><label>Extra Lesson <b>(optional)</b> N15,000.00</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="fee"  id="clu" value="15000.00"><label>Club <b>(optional)</b> N15,000.00</label><br>
<!--total fee is here-->   
<p><b>Total Fee:
<input  name="amt" id="amt" class="form-control number" type="text" /> <br>
```

And then, your script:

**With jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input[name=fee]').on('click', function() {
      var fee = 0;
      $('input[name=fee]:checked').each(function() {
         fee+=parseFloat($(this).val());
      });
      $('#amt').val(fee);
   });
});
```

**Or, without jQuery (using your `updateFee` function:**

```
// run this script after page finish loading
window.onload = function() {
    // get all the checkboxes you want to listen to
    var cbs = document.getElementsByName('fee');

    // attach click event for each one
    for(var i=0; i<cbs.length; i++) {
       cbs[i].onclick=updateFee;
    }
};
```

Comment: WOw! That was fast. I would prefer it in javascript as I am still trying to get a hang of javascript before jumping into jquery. Thanks. @Yaron U.

Comment: If you want to bind multiple events to a single event on a single control you can use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: @AbdulhakeemImran You will never need to jump into jQuery, and you should not, unless you enjoy taking trips back in time.

Comment: @AbdulhakeemImran Firstly, you didn't add the `updateFee` function to your fiddle. Secondly, JSFiddle runs the script inside `window.onload` callback - so in order to see it works in JSFiddle, you need to run it without the first and last lines